# How can I remove the white space below the "Brilliant" div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, removing-whitespace

[Screenshot of white space under div]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO7TV.jpg

I can't work out why this white space is visible, I am a newbie to coding and would greatly appreciate any help possible. I have tried googling the answer but have had no luck!

```css
 body{ background: rgb(245,245,245); color: green; font-size: 25px; font-family: Helvetica; margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none; border: 0; display: flex; } .card { font-weight: lighter; text-align: center; color: white; background: rgb(50, 50, 50); margin: 0; padding: 20px; }
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Welcome to Luke's first project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bellota' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      </head>

      <body>

        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="banner">
                        <h1>Welcome to my first project</h1>
                        <p>This is where I will be learning new skills and putting them into practice!</p>
                        <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Start now</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card">
                    <h2>Awesome</h2>
                    <p>Thanks for visiting</p>
                    </div>
                </div><div class="col">
                    <div class="card">
                    <h3>Brilliant</h3>
                    <p>Hope you're impressed</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="footer">
                        <p>Thank you for looking through my work and a special thanks to ©Le Wagon for teaching me!</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                             <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                             <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                             <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                             <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Relevant CSS

    body{
      background: rgb(245,245,245);
      color: green;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      outline: none;
      border: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
   
    .card {
      font-weight: lighter;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px;
    }

Comment: always try to post a working snippet.  You will get answers a lot faster.  Here's your's as a snippet.  What's the problem as the snippet does not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have all your code, but I think it is because you have an h2 tag in the first card-section and then a h3 in the next. Try and change to both h2 or h3 and see if the whitespace dissapears.

```html
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <h3>Awesome</h3>
            <p>Thanks for visiting</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card">
            <h3>Brilliant</h3>
            <p>Hope you're impressed</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you I've changed them both to H2 and it works perfectly now! Would you happen to know why it wouldn't work with them being different headings?

Comment: When using different sizes of headings like in this case, it pushes the size of the card as well. Thats why you had a diff when one card was heading h2 and one card was h3, it simply pushed them to be different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-white">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm p-3 text-center">
            <h3>Awesome</h3>
            <p>Thanks for visiting</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm p-3 text-center">
            <h3>Brilliant</h3>
            <p>Hope you're impressed</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use the piece of code above.
I hope my answer will help you.